# i'm able to connect to database through server_ip/phpMyadmin but not able to connect through xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp, privileges, sql-grant

i'm able to connect to database through `http://server_ip/phpMyadmin/` but not able to connect through xampp.

I have provided same login credentials in `config.inc.php`

Please help me to resolve this issue.

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 server, php7.0, mysql5.7

Comment: Please provide more information. What error do you see? error 500? or it says your password is wrong? did you try `http://127.0.0.1/phpMyadmin/` ?

Comment: @ICE: i'm getting this error while trying to connect through xampp http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/4262/SRAPKd.png 
But i'm able to connect phpmyadmin through server ip address.

is there mysql ubuntu configuration required to connect using xampp, means outside of ip ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't configure correct port or host.

1. change host to the `127.0.0.1`
2. open terminal and run `netstat -tln` then you can check what is the `tcp` port. for me it's `3306`. then you can set that port inside config.

You can also use mysql query to find out what is your mysql port. Open terminal and run `mysql -u  root -p` and then enter your mysql password. now you can run this query to find out what is your port number.

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';
```

Mysql is using 3306 port by default. you can change it to what you want:

1. open terminal and run `sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`
2. find `port=` under `[mysqld]` and change to the port you want.
3. save it and restart mysql by this:

   `sudo service mysql restart`

If none of these help you, maybe commenting this line inside `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` can help. change

```
bind-address 127.0.0.1
```

to the

```
#bind-address 127.0.0.1
```

*restart mysql after that.*

Comment: thank you for your prompt reply. Please let me know which port i have to use http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/406/YEPG2Z.png

Comment: It seems you are using 3306. I updated my answer. maybe it can help you.

Comment: Still i'm not able to connect to the mysql server, Same error is displaying